# Using QProcess with a string containing path to file for execution

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt.
Can anyone tell me how to use string inside `QProcess`?
To be more clear I am making a image convertor in which I take target file path of png file to a string using `QFileDialog`.
Now I have a exe file which does all conversion of png to jpeg and I need to do somehing like this:

```
convertor.exe  path/to/png/file  path/for/storing/converted/output
```

How I can do this in Qt?

```
QProcess conv;
conv.start("C:/converter.exe" ??) what to do here?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give the arguments to the process as a QStringList:

```
QStringList args;
args << "path/to/png/file" << "path/for/storing/converted/output";
QProcess conv;
conv.start("C:/converter.exe", args);
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this :D Cannot vote up as I have reputation<15 :D

Comment: Varun Chitre: You can accept the answer though if it helped you.

Comment: Instead of QStringList args can we use QString args?

Comment: Yes. See [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#start-2). But I have usually found it more convenient and less error prone to use QStringList. For example, if your paths can contain spaces, it is _much_ easiers to use the QStringList version.

Answer (score 1):

Arguments to QProcess are passed in a QStringList: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#start

```
QStringList args;
args << pathToPng << pathToOutput
QProcess conv;
conv.start("c:/converter.exe", args);
```